# How to generate Create Script using SSMS Console

Tags: sql-server, ssms, sql-server-2014

I am trying to generate a create script using SQL SERVER MANAGEMENT STUDIO wizard. I right clicked on Database --> task --> Generate Script and selected the Table.
But, when I pasted the script from clipboard, it is coming out as

[image]

So, can anyone please let me know how to avoid that alter table script at the bottom. I just want one single CREATE Script including all the 10 columns. Thanks

Comment: That's how you created the table. You probably add Original, Scheduled and Note after the initial creation. With the wizard you won't be able to create another script than this with this table.

Comment: I usually right click the table and script table as.  I have never seen anything like this using my method or the one you describe.  Not even if I use an alter table to add a column.  My only guess is that the ansi padding has something to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid the separate ALTER statements by changing the SSMS scripting options. From the SSMS menu Tools-->Options-->SQL Server Object Explorer-->Scripting, set the Generate ANSI PADDING command commands option to false.

The reason some of the columns are scripted as `ALTER` statements is because the columns have different ANSI_PADDING settings. The session ANSI_PADDING setting that was in effect with the columns were added is part of column meta-data. `ANSI_PADDING ON` (recommended) retains trailing spaces per the ANSI SQL standard whereas `ANS_PADDING OFF` removes them. The `OFF` setting is to only to provide legacy Sybase compatibility.

In my experience, `ANS_PADDING OFF` is often set inadvertently due to inattention to session settings. One seldom wants or needs to remove trailing spaces from values supplied during inserts and updates. It's best to always make sure the `ANS_PADDING ON` session setting is in effect when creating or altering tables.